# how to URL Routing like this in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose I have a controller called "getproduct". If i use this

> http://example.com/getproduct/ad29i

the getproduct controller extract the product code(i.e ad29i,ci013,ze529) from that url and display the required result.

Now i want to setup this url like

```
http://example.com/ad29i
http://example.com/ci013
http://example.com/ze529
```

How to achive this?

**my .htaccess file content**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have set config file like this

**$config['index_page'] = '';**

Answer (score 0):

Go to `routes.php`

```
$route['(:any)''] = 'getproduct/value';
```

[routes Codeigniter Examples](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html?highlight=routes#examples)

Comment: Can you tell me suppose I have other controller like product mean if I access product controller like example.com/product then does it redirect to getproduct? I am new in codeigniter.

Comment: Do like this `$route['getproduct''] = 'product';`

Comment: Getproduct cntroller route to product.but I don't need this.